# How to Call Undefined Methods Sequentially in Python Class

Tags: python, oop

With ***getattr***, I can do it like this : `myclass.method1()`

But I'm looking for something like  `myclass.method1().method2()` or `myclass.method1.method2()`.

It means that `method1`, `method2` are not defined in the class.

*Is there any way to call **undefined methods** sequentially in a Python class?*

Comment: @hiroprotagonist for example `method1` and `method2` are not defined in `myclass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what exactly that I've looked for:

```
class MyClass:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        setattr(self, name, self)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # calling required methods with args & kwargs
            return self
        return wrapper
```

Then I can call undefined methods sequentially like so:

```
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.method1().method2().method3()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but it seems that what you are calling the **undefined method** is actually a normal method which you just want to call by name (because you obviously can not call something that is really not defined).

In this case, you can nest `getattr` as many times as you need to go deeper, here is an example:

```
class Test:
    def method_test(self):
        print('test')


class Another:
    def __init__(self):
        self._test = Test()
    def method_another(self):
        print('Another')
        return self._test

another = Another()
getattr(
    getattr(another, 'method_another')(),
    'method_test'
)()
```

The last statement actually does `another.method_another().method_test()`.

Answer (score 0):

@Mortezaipo: You should set the attribute to the wrapper method, otherwise you can call the undefined methods only once:

```
class MyClass:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # calling required methods with args & kwargs
            return self
        setattr(self, name, wrapper)
        return wrapper
```